# Querying considering 2 or more columns of database. (Rails 3.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am implementing an ecommerce website where I have products of various categories `(CategoryA, CategoryB, CategoryC, ...)` and from various stores `(StoreA, StoreB, StoreC, ...)`.

I was successful in implementing `show_by_category` and `show_by_store` method which returned products from db of particular category and store respectively. But I am not sure about how to implement `show_by_category_in_store` where user is showed a list of products of same category available in particular store, and show_by_store_in_category. My models are Products, Category and Store

```
 def show_by_category
  @title = "#{Category.find(params[:id]).name}"
  @products = Category.find(params[:id]).products
 end

 def show_by_college
   @title = "#{College.find(params[:id]).name}"
   @products =[]
   Store.within(3, :units=>:km, :origin=>[Store.find(params[:id]).lat, Store.find(params[:id]).lng]).order('distance ASC').each {|c| @products << c.products}
 end
```

A product `belongs_to` category and store, a store and category `has_many` products. 
Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the convention, `show_by_category_and_store` (`_and_` as opposed to `_in_`) to achieve this, and then pass in both the category and store id.

So:

`@products = Product.find_by_category_and_store(@category, @store)`

Which will give you products that are only in both the specified Category **and** Store.

See the [ActiveRecord::Base documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), specifically the section titled "Dynamic attribute-based finders" for more examples showing finds with multiple column names.

Comment: any insight on how could I write view for this. I am paused at passing two arguments. How would I collect them from view?

Comment: I don't understand. The products are returned in the `@products` variable, which is automatically available in the view. In your view, you just reference the `@products` variable like any other collection of objects, and use that to list the products on your page.